# Counting accepted answers towards tag badges

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, badges, accepted-answer

As far as I can tell, tag scoring (used as a counter towards a `tag badge`) measures score based on how many upvotes all answers under a certain tag have gathered. It does not count `accepted answers` however.

I was wondering why is this the case, and whether this can/should be changed. Presumably, one would like to avoid having an OP generate two scores with an upvote + accepted. However, oftentimes new users have no upvoting privileges and thus can only accept an answer. Even when they do upvote and accept, it can be said that it deserves two scores.

Comment: Thanks! Edited as suggested verbatim

Comment: This would be a system-wide change that would need to be implemented by the SE developers. The place for such requests is [meta.SE]--we have no say over the issue. That said, I'm pretty sure this has been asked on meta.SE already. My solution would be for OPs to automatically have the privilege of upvoting answers to their own questions, even if they can't upvote otherwise. That has also been raised before, & has been declined emphatically based on the reasoning that it would be inappropriate for new users to award 10 points (but it is OK for them to award 15), to inhibit cheating.

Comment: Declining for the reasons listed by animuson. Vote early & vote often!

Answer (score 7):

This kind of change is widely unpopular - not because people don't think a change should be made, but because this is a very "meh" kind of change.

Yes, the current system is somewhat unfair to those users who never get upvotes but frequently get accepted answers. They essentially never make any progress like those users who do get upvotes on their answers and experience no problems. However, starting to count accepted answers into the equation doesn't solve the problem. All it does is shift the problem in the other direction. Now those users who only ever get accepted answers are making progress, but those users who *do* get upvotes are essentially doubling their progress for no apparent reason.

And therein lies a bigger problem. This change potentially makes it twice as easy to get the tag badges. If tag badges didn't mean anything like the others, we frankly wouldn't care, but gold tag badges give users heightened privileges on questions with that tag, and we have to be careful not to make it *too* easy for that privilege to be obtained. Allowing this change would likely mean we'd have to modify the criteria for the tag badges to make them more difficult to obtain based on the new system, so any progress you'd make by counting the accepted answers would likely be diminished by the increased criteria for the badge.

As said before, this kind of change doesn't solve the problem at hand. All it does is increase the benefit for a minority that have trouble getting upvotes on their accepted answers, when there is probably a much better solution out there somewhere that doesn't overcompensate another minority.

Comment: +1, for not duplicating points; but the system could award a point for accepted answers without upvotes from OP. That would address all points made in your answer, wouldn't it?

Comment: @AndreSilva That change makes it impossible for regular users to audit their tag score, because they can't possibly know if the upvote on the post is from the OP or not, thus they couldn't know if they needed to count 1 or 2. We're not huge fans of just displaying more numbers that the user can't determine on their own.